# Is it possible to extend private function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, extend

I would like to override private function of lightbox library.

This is the part of its code:

```
$.fn.lightBox = function(settings) {

    var jQueryMatchedObj = this; // This, in this context, refer to jQuery object

    function _set_interface()
    {
        //....
    }

    function _start(objClicked,jQueryMatchedObj) {
        //...
        _set_interface();
        //...
    }

    function _initialize() {
    _start(this,jQueryMatchedObj);
        return false;
    }

    return this.unbind('click').click(_initialize);
}
```

I need override _set_interface function. Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible. That's why they are called "private"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible....

You have no access to that private scope of the plugin.

Which as (@crush says below in the comments) is the entire point of private functions (or scope).